# jQuery syntax for finding row index in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

1) How do I find the row number/index in a HTML table? The generated table doesn't have any id for row.

eg: I have a plain HTML table generated, which has 10 rows,
I am adding rows dynamically to this table.(in between existing rows)

Since I am adding new row, the existing row index will change. Now I need to to find the index of each row before adding the new row.

Comment: The very best reference site for jQuery is, unsurprisingly, the jQuery site itself; in particular the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *"1) How do i find the row number/index in a HTML table? The generated table dosen't have any id for row."*

If you mean that you already have a row, and you need its index, don't use jQuery to get it. Table rows maintain their own index via the `rowIndex` property.

```
$('table tr').click(function() {

    alert( this.rowIndex );  // alert the index number of the clicked row.

});
```

***Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/LsSXy/

Answer (score 1):

To get the index of any element within a selector use `index()`.

In your case it would be:

```
var rowIndex = $("#myTable TR").index();
```

In addition, you can use `eq()` to select a specific element in a group:

```
var thirdRow = $("#myTable TR").eq(2) // zero based .: 2 = 3rd element.
```

[Read more on `info`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)
[Read more on `eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery site is really good for finding functions, I always find myself going back to it all the time for reference and  refresh. http://docs.jquery.com/

Or you can use css selectors in jquery like so

`$('table tr td:first').addClass('first-row');`