# Get current rowIndex of table in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My table cell gets highlighted when clicked. I need to find the rowIndex of highlighted cell. 
I tried doing like this

```
$(".ui-state-highlight").index(); // Results to 0
```

I tried this too...

```
$('td').click(function(){

    var row_index = $(this).parent().index('tr');

    var col_index = $(this).index('tr:eq('+row_index+') td');

    alert('Row # '+(row_index)+' Column # '+(col_index));

}); 
// Results : Row # -1 Column # -1
```

I went to through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096682/jquery-syntax-for-finding-row-index-in-a-html-table) post and tried the first answer, still couldn't get the result.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('td').click(function(){
   var row_index = $(this).parent().index();
   var col_index = $(this).index();
});
```

If you need the index of table contain td then you can change it to

```
var row_index = $(this).parent('table').index();
```

Comment: The cell get the class (.ui-state-highlight) so according to your ans i should use $('.ui-state-highlight').parent().index(); .It returns 2 where the highlighted cell is in 4 row considering 0 based.

Comment: You need to use this, If you want the row index of td then $(this).parent().index(); and if you need the index of table contain td then you can change it to $(this).parent('table').index();

Answer (score 15):

Since "$(this).parent().index();" and "$(this).parent('table').index();" don't work for me, I use this code instead:

```
$('td').click(function(){
   var row_index = $(this).closest("tr").index();
   var col_index = $(this).index();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(this).closest("TR").index()
```

This one is also useful in dynamics rendering.