# How do I get current rowindex of a table using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

Can I get current row index of a table in Javascript  and can we remove the row of table with current Index that we got?

Comment: What is a current row? - Also, possible duplicate of [Get Current rowIndex of Table in Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152369/get-current-rowindex-of-table-in-jquery)

Comment: sorry i mean Can we get specific index of row?

Comment: Answer right in the link above

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy The link above is for jQuery, not pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 18):

> The rowIndex property returns the position of a row in table

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  console.log("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `rowIndex` is undefined?

Comment: rowIndex is a property of TR. So you have to find the matching TR first.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using JQuery, use method [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
var index = $('table tr').index(tr);
```

If no JQuery used, you can loop through all the TR element to find the matched TR.

```
var index = -1;
var rows = document.getElementById("yourTable").rows;
for (var i=0;i<rows.length; i++){
    if ( rows[i] == YOUR_TR ){
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: but i am not using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

To find the current row/column you might find this code useful. Note that I've used parentNode to get the <tr> needed for rowIndex :

```js
var table = document.getElementById("clickTable");
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {    
      for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++){
        table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
          r = this.parentNode.rowIndex;  
          c = this.cellIndex;
          alert("you clicked on\n column: "+c+"\n row:"+r);
        };
      }
    }
```

```html
    <table id="clickTable" border="1" cellpadding="15">
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>B1</td><td>C1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A2</td><td>B2</td><td>C2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A3</td><td>B3</td><td>C3</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, whenever I want to know what the index is of the row a certain element is in, I use closest() and index(). For example:

```
$('#MyTable').on('click', 'input', function() {
   var rowIndexOfElement = $(this).closest("tr").index();
   DoSomethingWithTheRow(rowIndexOfElement);
});
```

Answer (score -3):

By default the event object will contain the rowindex property

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  var txt = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    txt = txt + "The index of Row " + (i + 1) + " is: " + x[i].rowIndex + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: your example is broken

Comment: miss `id="demo"` for `<table>` element