# Get table row index from row ID in TypeScript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a table. Each row has an ID.

Can I get the index of any row by using only its ID (no click) and without using a loop?

My HTML looks like this:

```
<table id="tabId">
<tr id="a">
    <td>ss</td>
    <td>ss</td>
</tr>
<tr id="b">
    <td>kk</td>
    <td>kk</td>
</tr>
```

I tried this:

```
var row_number = document.getElementById('a').rowIndex;
```

but it's not working; I get an [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2f6y.png) saying:

> [ts] Property 'rowIndex' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

Comment: It's a [property and not a method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex) -> `document.getElementById(a).rowIndex`

Comment: it's not a duplicate. already read that post.

Comment: @user2243952 here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37613166/3551786). And there `this` is same what you are getting by id.

Comment: no, that solution need to click on the row. I need the index using only the id

Comment: The click is only to get the row, so yes you would have to adjust it a little bit...

Comment: @Andreas OP is looking answer for typescript, now I am also confused, my answer does works for me, but why not for him.

Comment: [The property 'value' does not exist on value of type 'HTMLElement'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989741/the-property-value-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type-htmlelement) -> Cast as `HTMLTableRowElement`

Comment: @ Alexandru-IonutMihai: The OP has clarified in their comments that they're using TypeScript, for which the solutions given [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573622/how-do-i-get-current-rowindex-of-table-using-javascript) apparently don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var el = (document.getElementById('b')) as HTMLTableRowElement;
console.log(el.rowIndex);
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add `''` to the `getElementById()` function and you wrote `rowIndex` not as a property and wrong.

Here is a working example:

```js
var row_number = document.getElementById('a').rowIndex;
alert(row_number);
```

```html
<table id="tabId">
<tr id="a">
    <td>ss</td>
    <td>ss</td>
</tr>
<tr id="b">
    <td>kk</td>
    <td>kk</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: rowindex does not exist on type htmlelement.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote everything right? Can you post your code again?

Comment: @user2243952 Then you've done something wrong. Run the snippet and you will see that it works

Comment: i put a simpler example but my rows id is {{item.id}}. i'm using angular and typescript

Comment: Property 'rowIndex' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you if you don't post your code.

Comment: @user2243952 Then `document.getElementById(<whatever id your using>)` doesn't return a table row...

Comment: it does, using a loop I can get the row index matching my id.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('tabId').rows);
var row = document.getElementById('b');

console.log(rows.indexOf(row));
```

Here is an [Example](https://jsbin.com/zozazok/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: Property 'rows' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/zozazok/edit?html,js,console

Comment: @klugjo, it always a good idea to add additional explanation such as (example links) to the answer body itself.

Comment: Got it. I created the example after the comment saying it does not work. Will think of editing my answer instead next time

Answer (score 0):

special thx to @durga for his solution. I fixed it by explicitly typing variable as any.

```
var el : any = (document.getElementById('a')) as HTMLTableElement;
var index = el.rowIndex;
console.log(index);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can get using `on click on particulate tr` to get its `index`

or change you `Rowindex` to `rowIndex` and add `''` in `id of div 'a' in script`

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  console.log("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);
}
```

```html
<table id="tabId">
  <tr id="a" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>ss</td>
    <td>ss</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="b" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>kk</td>
    <td>kk</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: I m not going to click on the row.. I just want to get the row index by using the id only.

Comment: so put athore solution mistake by you in code so solve this

Answer (score -2):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[index].id;


<table id="tableId">
    <tr id="a">
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="b">
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
</table>

var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
var row = table.rows[index];
console.log(row.id);
```

Comment: The question is _"Can I get the row index of any row by its id whitout using a loop?"_ and not how to use this index O.o

Comment: i need the opposite of this.